# Getting Invalid merchant details (ERRP004) error while integrating Billdesk payment gateway

Tags: node.js, express, payment-gateway, payment

I am getting the below error, when calling the billdesk UAT url,

> Sorry we are uable to process your request right now - Invalid
> merchant details (ERRP004).

I have followed all the steps of generating piped message as mentioned in Billdesk document but still giving error. Have you ever got this error while integration ? If then what is the reason it gives error and how did you solved it. My technology platform is node js,express

**Steps i did**

1. Prepared pipe seprated message
2. generated checksum for the message using HMACSHA256 algo
3. appended that checksum to the end of the message
4. prepared Ejs form that submits when loaded and added msg parameter
   in it
5. call the ejs using res.render()

Comment: There might be some issue with the generated hash..u can use a node library to do all these https://www.npmjs.com/package/billdeskjs

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved and the reason behind this issue was that the checksum generated was lowercase and it was to be appended to the end of the msg string that need to send hence was giving error. So check that every thing in the msg string should be uppercase except numbers

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether key and salt are stored correctly in database. I faced this issue recently. Database column size was lesser than expected due to which the salt got truncated and gave the above error.
2. msg string generated needs to be in capital letters.